# How do you get value from multidimential object when name path is stored in array of unknown length?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm creating a folder directory and need to allow users to navigate within it. I have a global variable that stores their location in the directory. How can I access the content within their selected folder.

This is what I what.

```
let location = ["2022","March","Week4"];
let content = folderInformation["2022"]["March"]["Week4"];
```

However, the file names "2022, March, Week4, ect" are set by the user.

So I could do this.

```
let location = ["2022","March","Week4"];
let layer1 = location[0];
let layer2 = location[1];
let layer3 = location[2];
let content = folderInformation[layer1][layer2][layer3];
```

However, the user could be 2 layers deep or 15.

I tried

```
let layers = location.join("][");
let content = folderInformation[layers];
```

and

```
let layers = "["+location.join("][")+"]";
let content = folderInformation+layers;
```

with no success. What is the best option to access the content within the object?

Comment: just loop through the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short version with reduce:

```js
const content = location.reduce((o,l)=>o?.[l],folderinformation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array of `locations` and access every location in the `folderInformation` object one by one. This way you will go one level deeper with each iteration.

```js
function getFolderInformation(folderInformation, locations) {
  let currentLocation = folderInformation;
  
  for (const location of locations) {
    if (location in currentLocation) {
      currentLocation = currentLocation[location];
    }
  }
  
  return currentLocation;
}

const folderInformation = {
  '2022': {
    'Februari': {
      'Week1': {
        title: 'Nope',
        description: 'Not this one'
      }
    },
    'March': {
      'Week3': {
        title: 'Also no',
        description: 'Wrong'
      },
      'Week4': {
        title: 'Foo',
        description: 'Bar'
      },
    }
  }
};

let locations = ["2022", "March", "Week4"];
let content = getFolderInformation(folderInformation, locations);

console.log(content);
```